# Cognos 8.4.1 / TFS Integration

Tags: cognos-8

My team uses TFS 2010 for source control, build, etc. for all of our .NET and Java projects, and we would like to do the same for our Cognos reports.  Today we have to export the Cognos reports from the development environment into an XML file, which we can then store in the source code repository.  This is obviously not optimal and leaves the process open for mistakes.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to integrate Cognos reports into TFS?  I'm open to using the SDK and writing some minor integrations if necessary, but I'd like to know if it's even possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We also export reports to XML, and then manually maintain them in our version control system. You could if you wanted to, as you suggest, use the Cognos SDK to write a utility that handles this for you. The SDK gives you the ability to do this. Alternatively, you could use one of the existing third party tools that are available out there that put version control into Cognos Connection for you. Examples include:-

1. [MotioCI](http://www.motio.com/products/ci/overview.do) from Motio
2. [Integrated Control Suite](http://www.bspsoftware.com/Products/ImplementationBasedSoftware/IntegratedControlSuite/tabid/233/Default.aspx) from BSP

Obviously, the upside of using the SDK is you save yourself money, and you can integrate things into your existing VCS. On the downside, you have the time it takes you to do it, and the possibility of bugs.

The upside of using one of the products listed above is that you get a very mature solution which goes even beyond simple code control like you're thinking of. The downside is that you have to have the money for it.

Hope these thoughts help, and just to be clear, I have no connection with either of the companies linked to above.